# Hidden php extension url

Tags: .htaccess, url, hidden, file-extension

im trying hide the extension files of the URL, on my web project. For example, i wish that the next URL: "local.pilarme.com.ar/owner/contacto.php" shows how "local.pilarme.com.ar/owner/contacto".
I put in my root folder (local.pilarme.com.ar) an .htaccess file with this content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
```

But, when i try "local.pilarme.com.ar/owner/contacto" error 404 appear.
I have active mod_rewrite in my apache 2 install:

```
root@rastrojero:/home/ramiro#  apache2ctl -M
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 ......................
 **rewrite_module (shared)**
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

In the sites-enabled file i enable the option AllowOverride:

```
<Directory /media/Datos/www/PilarMedicinaEstetica  >
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

Is the first time that do. Any ideas ?.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. In some servers is necesary specify: **Options -Multiviews** to dont show 404 error ^^. Htaccess finally:

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```